# '_lifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true. Error in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I've encountered an error which says

```
'_lifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
```

[image]

I came across this issue when I tried to change the state in dispose() method.

```
      @override
      void dispose() {
        setState(() => _successErrorLoader = "");
        setState(() => _ackMessage = "");
      }
```

I want to do some state changes when an component is unmounted (removed from the screen). Please provide any alternative solution or a fix for this error.

Comment: If dispose is called, the widget won't be displayed anymore, and setState wouldn't affect anything. What you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to change values of some of the variables after the widget is removed

Comment: What do you want to happen with changed variables? How do you want to use their values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution I was looking for from Flutter themselves.

```
if(mounted){
  setState((){});
}
```

I was able to remove the error using the above solution

please check this issue : `https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99049`

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in changing some variables inside state after the `State` object is disposed. Let's say you've managed to change it using `setState`, how are you supposed to use that when it's disposed and the `build` method is not going to get called? It would be easier to help if you could explain what you have in mind and why you need to set something after dispose.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a misunderstanding on your part regarding how the lifecycle of a `stateful widget` works.
Setting the values of `state` variables inside the `dispose` does not lead to anything, as the `state` itself **(and all the variables contained in it)** will be eliminated during dispose.

Based on the values you are setting, I assume your goal is to get clean values for the next time the object is instantiated.

If these variables are declared as empty, then you don't need all this, as when instantiating the new `state`, these variables will take empty value or whatever you give them.

Having no further context, I still leave you a possible solution to initialize the variables during the `initState`:

```
late String _successErrorLoader;
late String _ackMessage;

@override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      _successErrorLoader = '';
      _ackMessage = '';
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you want to set `_ackMessage = ""` and set `_ackMessage = ""` when the widget (or more precisely, the state) is disposed. That's completely fine.

The problem comes with the `setState` call. In Flutter, `setState` means, "please rebuild this widget in the next frame". However, because your widget is being disposed (it's being deleted) there won't be a "next frame". It will never build again, hence the error message.

To resolve it, you can just assign the variables **without `setState`**, because the widget is being disposed, it won't ever rebuild again, it does not make any difference whether you call `setState` or not. For example:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _successErrorLoader = "";
    _ackMessage = "";
  }
```

However, it's also quite likely that you don't need to set these variables to `""` either. If they are member variables, they will be deleted when the widget is disposed. Noone will ever access them again, so it doesn't matter what their value is, hence there's no need to clear them.